# Should I say "creation of A and B" or "creation of A and of B"? (B being plural)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conjunction-reduction

As a student, I need to write a report about what I accomplished during an internship. I created two things: some indicators (A) and a dashboard (B).
Should the title of my report be "Creation of indicators and a dashboard" or "Creation of indicators and of a dashboard"?

I find "creation of A and B" better, but I'm not really sure, and the fact than the first item is plural while the second is singular makes me hesitate...

I tried to find some help or examples on the Internet, but could only find results about the creation of something, nothing that could help me with the use of this word...

Comment: Forget creation, this is not a biblical text, right? "I created [use a verb] indicators and a dashboard".

Comment: @Lambie No, it's not a biblical text, but I didn't find any other way to say that I created/built something... This kind of report always have a title like "amelioration of something", there's never a verb in the title, that's why I'm looking for a way to say it like that. But as non-English speaker, it's possible that there's a similar term that I didn't think of...

Comment: I would stay away from creation. In marketing oneself with CVs and so forth, action verbs are preferred to abstract nouns: created the sales and marketing department in a small company. "Indicator and dashboard creation" would work. You can adjectify like that in English.

Comment: @Lambie Well, in France, it's the exact opposite ^^ I think I'll put it like that on my CV. Do you know if there's another word that carries the same meaning of creating/building something new?

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, I didn't see your edit ^^ I can't believe I didn't think of making them the adjectives... It's so simple! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, in the business and tech world, adjectivizing nouns is big business (ahem).  Yes, crafting. However, there is probably a higher-level word you might use. A dashboard with indicators is in a field. Crafting a Dashboard with Indicators to Boost Sales. [they're gonna kick me outta here. :)]

Comment: C'est une déformation professionnelle.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, that's the right term... ;) Although I was under the impression that adjectivizing nouns was something most English-speaking people did, not just those in the business and tech world...

Comment: Yes, that's right but it is especially prevalent in those areas. Or other technical areas like patents.

Answer (score 1):

"Creation of A and B" sounds more correct in spite of one being singular and the other, plural.